# Magento 2 Model override does not work

Tags: magento2, overrides, model

I'm trying to override core Model `Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap` with my own model `My\Namespace\Model\Sitemap` as follows,

```
<preference for="Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap"    type="My\Namespace\Model\Sitemap" />
```

All other my overridden Models and Blocks are working fine, but for some strange reason, this override for Sitemap Model does not work,

My custom Model is almost same with only few changes inside of few methods.

```
<?php

namespace My\Namespace\Model;

class Sitemap extends \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap
{
    protected function _getSitemapRow($url, $lastmod = null, $changefreq = null, $priority = null, $images = null)
    {
        $url = $this->_getUrl($url);
        $row = '<locS>' . htmlspecialchars( $url ) . '</locS>';
        if ($lastmod) {
            $row .= '<lastmod>' . $this->_getFormattedLastmodDate($lastmod) . '</lastmod>';
        }
        if ($changefreq) {
            $row .= '<changefreq>' . $changefreq . '</changefreq>';
        }
        if ($priority) {
            $row .= sprintf('<priority>%.1f</priority>', $priority);
        }
        if ($images) {
            foreach ($images->getCollection() as $image) {
                $row .= '<image:image>';
                $row .= '<image:loc>' . htmlspecialchars($this->_getMediaUrl($image->getUrl())) . '</image:loc>';
                $row .= '<image:title>' . htmlspecialchars($images->getTitle()) . '</image:title>';
                if ($image->getCaption()) {
                    $row .= '<image:caption>' . htmlspecialchars($image->getCaption()) . '</image:caption>';
                }
                $row .= '</image:image>';
            }
            $row .= '<PageMap xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-pagemap/1.0"><DataObject type="thumbnail">';
            $row .= '<Attribute name="name" value="' . htmlspecialchars($images->getTitle()) . '"/>';
            $row .= '<Attribute name="src" value="' . htmlspecialchars(
                $this->_getMediaUrl($images->getThumbnail())
            ) . '"/>';
            $row .= '</DataObject></PageMap>';
        }

        return '<url>' . $row . '</url>';
    }

    protected function _getSitemapIndexRow($sitemapFilename, $lastmod = null)
    {
        $url = $this->getSitemapUrl($this->getSitemapPath(), $sitemapFilename);
        $row = '<locS>' . htmlspecialchars( $url ) . '</locS>';
        if ($lastmod) {
            $row .= '<lastmod>' . $this->_getFormattedLastmodDate($lastmod) . '</lastmod>';
        }

        return '<sitemap>' . $row . '</sitemap>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Your overridden model should work, we need to clear cache, var generation. And try again.

Comment: show your custom model code

Comment: added the code to the question

Comment: Can you please try to make your function `public` instead of `private` & check? If it dosen't work copy whole class & add ur changes & check `class Sitemap extends \Magento\Sitemap\Model\Sitemap` remains Same

Comment: does not work, but to override I think the method should have the same access modifier. in this case ` protected`

Comment: after that have you `upgrade`  and  `recompile` your store?

Comment: I found out the issue, it was, another 3rd party module overwriting the same Model. So I disabled that module as I don't use it anymore.
Thanks for all the answers.